# Python Highlight_text add value from function

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, text, highlight

I'm trying to highlight some text using the highlight_text library:

```
s= '<Jugador1> and <Jugador2>  Premier League Passing Stats'
highlight_text.fig_text(s=s,
                x=.18, y=.90,
                #highlight_weights = ['bold'],
                fontsize=22,
                fontfamily = 'Andale Mono',
                color = text_color,
                highlight_textprops=[{"color": 'red', "fontweight": "bold"},
                                   {"color": 'blue', "fontweight": "bold"}],
                va='center'
               )
```

I want to define jugador1 and jugador2 in the function like so:

```
multi_beeswarm(Jugador1 = 'F. Zampedri', Jugador2 = 'L. Martínez Dupuy', background = '#313332')
```

How can I break the <> so that it takes the input set in the function and not the literal jugador1 and jugador2?

Expected output: 'F. Zampedri and L. Martínez Dupuy Premier League Passing Stats'

Comment: Could you please add a link to the `highlight_text` library you're using provide a MWE? It will make it easier for others to learn from your question and apply the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [f-string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals):

```
s = f"<{Jugador1}> and <{Jugador2}> Premier League Passing Stats"

highlight_text.fig_text(s=s,
                x=.10, y=.92,
                highlight_textprops=[{"color": "red", "fontweight": "bold"},
                                     {"color": "blue", "fontweight": "bold"}],
                va="center"
               )
```

[image]